# Create squares with a function and move a picture with an ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, maze

I want to make a maze game where I can move the figure around and can't go through the walls and get to the end of the maze. I can't make a function that makes a square everytime the database shows the number one. I also want to be able to move my player around, but not allow it to go through the maze walls.

Code:

```js
    var mazeData = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

var i = math.floor(Math.random() * 48)

function drawMaze() {
    if (mazedata[i] == 1) {
        drawSquare;
    }

    function drawSquare() {

    }
}

if (e.keycode == 37)
    player.attrs.x -= 10
if (e.keycode == 38)
    player.attrs.y += 10
if (e.keycode == 39)
    player.attrs.x += 10
if (e.keycode == 40)
    player.attrs.y -= 10
```

[maze game](https://codepen.io/Robotechnology/pen/LaXXZR)

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Are you asking a question or did you just want to inform us?

Comment: You haven't asked us a question or described a problem. what do you need help with, exactly?